# Fixing RAID on PERC S100

Tags: raid, dell-perc

I had 3 hard drives in this server.  The controller read that disk 0:0 was READY (not online) and there were 2 Virtual Disks.  (One was my VD and the other was a mysterious non-RAID VD that I assume was created because disk 0:0 was in a Ready state)

My main VD was listed as degraded.

To be safe since I was not sure what disk 0:0 was up to, I put a 4th hard drive in and assigned it as Global Hot Spare and it went through a rebuild.  Once finished, now my VD has physical disks 0:1, 0:2, 0:3 stating all online, but the VD still says FAILED.  Physical Disk 0:3 (the new one) looks to be part of the group but it is still listed as a global spare?

I am at a loss here how to get the VD back to good.

Comment: What RAID level was it?  0, 1, 5?

Comment: Sorry - it is a RAID 5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like disk 0:0 failed to begin with, leaving it no longer showing as an active member of the RAID5 VD. The S100 seems to be a bit quirky as to how it handles drive failures and the labeling of previously-failed drives, so confusion over situations like this isn't uncommon.

If you have another replacement hard drive available, I'd recommend swapping it with disk 0:0. I'm not certain whether the S100 will copy data back to slot 0 from the global spare slot or not - if it doesn't, you may need to try to find an option to make the spare the new permanent replacement drive (possibly an option in OMSA - unsure whether the operation will be supported with the S100).

Comment: What I have now is a VD with 3 Hard Drives all showing online as I unassigned the new drive as a hot spare and it looks to be a part of the RAID now.  Now OMSA says the RAID is failed rather than degraded yet is has 3 drives assigned and all reporting healthy.  Really hating this S100 and how OMSA is reporting it.  Leaving disk 0:0 alone and in a Ready state.